# AWS Simple AD: "KDC has no support for encryption type" for users created with adtool, but not with MS Management Console

Tags: openldap, kerberos, pam, sssd, aws-directory-service

## Background

I am trying to log in (via SSH, to an Amazon Linux EC2 instance running `sssd`) as users that I've created in my AWS Directory Services Simple AD. I am authenticating with kerberos and identifying the user with LDAP (all through `sssd`.)

### Problem

I cannot log in as users that I created with `adtool`, which means that it's much harder for me to automate adding new users to my Simple AD. When I try, KDC says that it can't support the encryption type (I assume this is for the user's password?) See the "Error message" section below.

However, I *can* log in as both the built-in Administrator user and as users that I've created through the Microsoft Management Console on a Windows Server 2008 EC2 instance joined to the domain. So my setup works, or at least it partially works.

### TL;DR solution needed

I need to know what it is that I'm doing wrong with `adtool` that prevents me from logging in as users created with them. It's not apparent what I am doing wrong and I think this could be generally useful for people trying to do something similar to me. Details below.

---

## Error message

This is the output of `sssd` when trying to log in as the user created with `adtool`:

```
(Thu Dec 31 15:35:35 2015) [[sssd[krb5_child[5459]]]] [sss_child_krb5_trace_cb] (0x4000): [5459] 1451576135.446649: Response was from master KDC

(Thu Dec 31 15:35:35 2015) [[sssd[krb5_child[5459]]]] [sss_child_krb5_trace_cb] (0x4000): [5459] 1451576135.446788: Received error from KDC: -1765328370/KDC has no support for encryption type

(Thu Dec 31 15:35:35 2015) [[sssd[krb5_child[5459]]]] [get_and_save_tgt] (0x0020): 996: [-1765328370][KDC has no support for encryption type]
(Thu Dec 31 15:35:35 2015) [[sssd[krb5_child[5459]]]] [map_krb5_error] (0x0020): 1065: [-1765328370][KDC has no support for encryption type]
(Thu Dec 31 15:35:35 2015) [[sssd[krb5_child[5459]]]] [k5c_send_data] (0x0200): Received error code 1432158209
```

From the client side it says `Permission denied, please try again.`

## Architecture

Here's what my architecture around the Simple AD looks like:

[image: Architecture diagram]

This setup enables me to use LDAPS even though AWS' Simple AD does not support it.

The route53 record for the ELB is `directory.myteam.mycompany.com`, but the domain I used for the Simple AD is `myteam.mycompany.internal`.

## Configuration on the machine running sssd

`/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
reconnection_retries = 3
sbus_timeout = 30
services = nss, pam
domains = myteam

[nss]
default_shell = /bin/bash
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
ldap_user_home_directory = unixHomeDirectory

[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3
offline_credentials_expiration = 2
offline_failed_login_attempts = 3
offline_failed_login_delay = 5

[domain/myteam]
enumerate = true
cache_credentials = TRUE

id_provider = ldap

ldap_uri = ldaps://directory.myteam.mycompany.com
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
ldap_default_bind_dn = CN=test-user,CN=users,DC=myteam,DC=mycompany,DC=internal
ldap_default_authtok = REDACTED_PASSWORD
ldap_id_use_start_tls = true
ldap_schema = AD
ldap_force_upper_case_realm = true
ldap_id_mapping = true
ldap_search_base = CN=users,DC=myteam,DC=mycompany,DC=internal

ldap_user_uuid = none
ldap_group_uuid = none

chpass_provider = krb5
auth_provider = krb5
krb5_server = directory.myteam.mycompany.com
krb5_realm = MYTEAM.MYCOMPANY.INTERNAL
krb5_changepw_principal = kadmin/changepw
krb5_ccachedir = /tmp
krb5_ccname_template = FILE:%d/krb5cc_%U_XXXXXX
krb5_auth_timeout = 15
krb5_canonicalize = True
```

`/etc/sysconfig/authconfig`:

```
IPADOMAINJOINED=no
USEMKHOMEDIR=yes
USEPAMACCESS=no
CACHECREDENTIALS=yes
USESSSDAUTH=yes
USESHADOW=yes
USEWINBIND=no
PASSWDALGORITHM=sha512
FORCELEGACY=yes
USEFPRINTD=no
FORCESMARTCARD=no
USEDB=no
USELDAPAUTH=no
USEPASSWDQC=no
IPAV2NONTP=no
WINBINDKRB5=no
USELOCAUTHORIZE=yes
USEECRYPTFS=no
USECRACKLIB=yes
USEIPAV2=no
USEWINBINDAUTH=no
USESMARTCARD=no
USELDAP=yes
USENIS=no
USEKERBEROS=no
USESYSNETAUTH=no
USESSSD=yes
USEPWQUALITY=yes
USEHESIOD=no
```

In addition to these two files, I made sure to enable password authentication in `sshd_config` and enabled sssd in the pam modules with `sudo authconfig --updateall --enablesssd --enablesssdauth`.

`/etc/pam.d/system-auth`:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

### Software versions

- `uname -a`: `Linux ip-172-31-31-2 4.1.10-17.31.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Oct 24 01:31:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- `sssd` 1.12.2
- `adtool` 1.3.3
- `openldap-clients` 2.4.23-34.25.amzn1

## Differences between the users

To show how these users differ in my directory, here is the output of querying them with `ldapsearch` from the instance running `sssd`.

User created with `adtool` (edit: you'll see below that the `pwdLastSet` value is present, I believe this was not present earlier and its presence is the key to my answer):

```
$ ldapsearch -LLL  -H ldaps://directory.myteam.mycompany.com -D CN=Administrator,CN=users,DC=myteam,DC=mycompany,DC=internal -x -W '(cn=test-user)'
Enter LDAP Password:
dn: CN=test-user,CN=Users,DC=myteam,DC=mycompany,DC=internal
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: test-user
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20151230204358.0Z
displayName: Test user
uSNCreated: 3532
name: test-user
objectGUID:: ZhfGzcqLd06x2UBU3UNiZQ==
codePage: 0
countryCode: 0
primaryGroupID: 513
objectSid:: AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAHWfr9xoaXwKvEcuoUwQAAA==
accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
sAMAccountName: test-user
sAMAccountType: 805306368
userPrincipalName: test-user@myteam.mycompany.internal
objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=myteam,DC=mycompany,DC
 =internal
userAccountControl: 512
lockoutTime: 0
whenChanged: 20151231150317.0Z
uSNChanged: 3619
pwdLastSet: 130960477970000000
distinguishedName: CN=test-user,CN=Users,DC=myteam,DC=mycompany,DC=internal
```

User created through the Microsoft Management Console:

```
$ ldapsearch -LLL  -H ldaps://directory.myteam.mycompany.com -D CN=Administrator,CN=users,DC=myteam,DC=mycompany,DC=internal -x -W '(sAMAccountName=test-windows-2008)'
Enter LDAP Password:
dn: CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=myteam,DC=mycompany,DC=internal
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: Test User
sn: User
givenName: Test
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20151230223533.0Z
whenChanged: 20151230223534.0Z
displayName: Test User
uSNCreated: 3563
uSNChanged: 3563
name: Test User
objectGUID:: 2cuynP3/9EeRIm1fCUJ9jA==
userAccountControl: 512
codePage: 0
countryCode: 0
pwdLastSet: 130959885340000000
primaryGroupID: 513
objectSid:: AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAHWfr9xoaXwKvEcuoVwQAAA==
accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
sAMAccountName: test-windows-2008
sAMAccountType: 805306368
userPrincipalName: test-windows-2008@myteam.mycompany.internal
objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=myteam,DC=mycompany,DC
 =internal
distinguishedName: CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=myteam,DC=mycompany,DC=internal
```

Comment: Can't help with your specific question but wanted to note: Thanks for your efforts to describe your problem and the environment! Thumbs up! Very well done! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between my use of `adtool` and the MMC was that the MMC encouraged me to initalize the user's password but I had forgotten to do the same with my user created with `adtool`. The following steps resolved it, and reproducibly so:

```
$ adtool userunlock -w REDACTED_PASSWORD 'test-user'
$ adtool setpass -w REDACTED_PASSWORD  test-user REDACTED_PASSWORD
```

In my initial question, I had re-queried the original `test-user` this morning after a coworker had done the above steps to set the password, so the output shows that the password was set but last night when I was trying to log in it hadn't been set, hence the issue. When I tried to log in again today it worked, and after some sleuthing I found out this is why.

Now, I can only speculate as to why the "KDC has no support for encryption type" message appeared: since there was no password, there wasn't an encryption type. If I'm wrong I'd love to be corrected.

**TL;DR** one has to remember to unlock the user and set their password when using `adtool` instead of the MMC.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen errors like that before caused by one of the account options being set (in a non AWS environment) but I do not recall which exact property. Do the users created with `ADTool` have any extra "options" set compared to the users created with MMC? I'm not sure how to show these options with `LDAPSearch`. Two methods I do know how to use shown. You can also use `-prop *` with `Get-Aduser` to show ALL properties.

[image: acctOptions]

```
PS C:\temp> get-aduser mbe998 -prop DoesNotRequirePreAuth,UseDESKeyOnly

DistinguishedName     : CN=Mary Brown,OU=Junk,DC=acme,DC=com
DoesNotRequirePreAuth : True
Enabled               : False
GivenName             : Mary
Name                  : Mary Brown
ObjectClass           : user
ObjectGUID            : f7f30ebe-f91d-41de-b38e-ae29853b7291
SamAccountName        : mbe998
SID                   : S-1-5-21-3362165994-992225803-2260058754-129428
Surname               : Brown
UseDESKeyOnly         : True
UserPrincipalName     : mbe998@acme.com
```

Comment: That would have been reflected in the UserAccountControl attribute.

Comment: They do not differ in the UI dialog you show. When I try to run `get-aduser` I get an error saying `Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running`.

Comment: Use a network capture. The client will send an AS_REQ contains the encryption types it supports. The KDC will then respond that it requires pre-authentication and sends a list of its supported encryption types. Described in much detail here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/10/19/hunting-down-des-in-order-to-securely-deploy-kerberos.aspx